# Need help with Python delete old dirs script

Tags: python, linux

This is function i am using to delete old dirs in python

```
def delete_olddirs(days,file_path):
     numdays = 60*60*24*days
     now = time.time()

     for dir in os.listdir(file_path):
              r = file_path
              timestamp = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(r,dir))
              if now-numdays > timestamp:
                  try:
                       print "removing ",os.path.join(r,dir)
                       #shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(r,dir))  #uncomment to use
                  except Exception,e:
                       print e
                       pass
                  else:
                       print "some message for success"
```

The problem is everytime i see message `removing  . ....` i also see message

```
some message for success
```

I want to know why is else part executed everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

> The optional `else` clause is executed
>   if and when control flows off the end
>   of the `try` clause. [2] Exceptions in
>   the `else` clause are not handled by the
>   preceding `except` clauses.

Seems clear.

Answer (score 1):

The else bit is run on success, you are misunderstanding its purpose.
See: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

The `else` part of `try` is executed if there were no exceptions raised.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a try/except/else block. If the try block succeeds (nothing is caught with except), then the else block will be executed. This is the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    l=[]
    for dir in os.listdir(file_path):
        r = file_path
        timestamp = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(r,dir))
        if now-numdays > timestamp:
            try:
                print "removing ",os.path.join(r,dir)
                #shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(r,dir))  #uncomment to use
                l.append("%s" %os.path.join(r,dir))
            except Exception,e:
                 print e
    print "removed the following folders %s" %L
```